# SerialDataReceivedEventHandler not working c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to connect to arduino with C# program in windows forms.
I can send data from c# to the arduino but I want to get data from the arduino to the C# program.

I've tried the SerialDataReceivedEventHandler, but I don't get the data after the form is built...

what can I do?

```
       public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Init();

    }//end form 1

    private void Init()
    {
        try
        {
            arduinoPort = new SerialPort();
            arduinoPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            arduinoPort.PortName = "COM4";
            arduinoPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            arduinoPort.RtsEnable = true;//request to send true
            arduinoPort.DtrEnable = true;//arduino can send messages to the c# program
            arduinoPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(GetFromArduino);               
            arduinoPort.Open();
        }//end try

        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }

    }//end init


    private void GetFromArduino(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        //string arduinoInputString = arduinoPort.ReadLine();
        //Invoke(new Action(() => label1.Text = arduinoInputString));
        MessageBox.Show("does it work?");
    }//end get from arduino
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I don't know if it matters, but this what i did and it solved:
1. in the setup function of the arduino program i had a loop that ran on all the pins, now i specified it to the pins i really use.
2. i don't open the port in the form.cs, but in the program.cs and run a while loop that just check if the port is open. then, it gets the data without disturbing the form to run... 

**in the Program.cs:**


  public static SerialPort arduinoPort { get; set; }
    public static string arduinoInputString { get; set; }
    [STAThread]

    static void Main()
    {
        arduinoPort = new SerialPort();
        try
        {
            arduinoPort = new SerialPort();
            arduinoPort.BaudRate = 250000;
            arduinoPort.PortName = "COM4";
            //arduinoPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            //arduinoPort.RtsEnable = true;//request to send true
            //arduinoPort.DtrEnable = true;//arduino can send messages to the c# program
            ////arduinoPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(GetFromArduino);
            arduinoPort.DataReceived += DataReceivedHandler;
            arduinoPort.Open();
        }//end try
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine((ex.Message)); }

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());

        while (arduinoPort.IsOpen)//read data if the port is open
        {

        }



    }//end main

    static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort comm = (SerialPort)sender;
        arduinoInputString = comm.ReadExisting();
        Form1.label1.Text = arduinoInputString;//label to show the input string from arduino
    }//end get data from arduino
```

Answer (score 1):

`MessageBox.Show` isn't going to work from the `DataReceived` event

[SerialPort.DataReceived Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The DataReceived event is raised on a secondary thread when data is
>   received from the SerialPort object. Because this event is raised on a
>   secondary thread, and not the main thread, attempting to modify some
>   elements in the main thread, such as UI elements, could raise a
>   threading exception. If it is necessary to modify elements in the main
>   Form or Control, post change requests back using Invoke, which will do
>   the work on the proper thread

at best you need to do something like this

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => { MessageBox.Show(this, "text"); }));
```

However, if you really want to know if that event is fired, then use a break-point

[Using Breakpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx)

Lastly, if the event isnt fired, then you will have to consult the documentation for the device for the appropriate configuration of the device and the serial port.

Comment: it's invoked only when i start the c# program, it shows the messagebox, but not if the arduino print something...

Comment: @Nadav so are you saying the event only fires once?

Comment: yes, i'm running my c# program, get the messagebox (because the arduino write something) and then, during the runtime, the arduino writes something but nothing happen

Comment: it's arduino due. is it OK to use the 9600 serial?

Comment: @Nadav Try different baud rates, you need to know this information, and if you don't you just need to experiment with well known baud rates

Answer (score 0):

Make some handler method, for example

```
        private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
             SerialPort comm = (SerialPort)sender;
             string incoming_Data = comm.ReadExisting();
             this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
             {
                Console.WriteLine(incoming_Data + "\n");
             });          
        }
```

Then, make this method to the subscriber of ***DataRecieved*** event

```
arduinoPort.DataReceived += DataReceivedHandler;
```

***Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bd8f7ac8-67d5-4eb5-b679-c595f9c7536d/how-to-print-out-text-from-serialport-datareceived-event?forum=netfxbcl***

Comment: still not working even with that... :( it fires when i start my c# program, but not during the runtime